# option show value in table

Tags: php, html, sql

I have: Selector.php

```
<!--Selector-->
<?php
    $render->makeSelector($database);
    $render->makeDetailTable($database);
?>
```

Render.php

```
<?php
class render {
    private $pdo;

function makeSelector($database){
    //Get name and id data from the db. In an assoc array
    $results = $database->Selector();
    echo "<form name='form' id='selector'>";
    echo "<select multiple='multiple'>";
    // Loop trough the results and make an option of every train_name
    foreach($results as $res){
                echo "<option>" . $res['train_name'] . "</option>";
        }   
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br />" . "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' tabindex='2' />" . "</td>";
    echo "</form>";
    }


function makeDetailTable($database){
    //Get all data from database, in an assoc array
    $results = $database->getAllAssoc();

    //Make table headers
    ?>
    <div id="train_select_table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Train name</th>
            <th>Tare weight</th>
            <th>Number of bogies</th>
            <th>Number of axles</th>
            <th>min Wheel diameter</th>
            <th>Max wheel diameter</th>
        </tr>
    <div id="loopRow">
        <?php      
            foreach($results as $res){
            //Loop trough results, generate a tablerow every time
        ?>
        <tr>        
            <?php echo "<td>" . $res['train_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $res['tare_weight'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $res['number_of_bogies'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $res['number_of_axles'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $res['wheel_diameter_min'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $res['wheel_diameter_max'] . "</td>";
            ?> 
        </tr>
    <?php 
        } 
    ?>
    </div>
    </table>
    </div>
    <?php
    }


}
?>
```

And my functions in database.php

```
function selector() {
        $sql = "SELECT train_id, train_name FROM train_information";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }

function getAllAssoc() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM train_information";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
     }
```

Right now the page shows me a Selector (With all the "`train_name`" values. And that works.
And under that i have got a table. But right now, the table shows everything from the train_information table. But this is not good becuase:

I only want to show information that the customer selected. So you go to the site. The table is empty. You select a few trains from the selector, and press submit. When you press submit, i only want to show the selected trains in the table, instead of everything.

How do i do this?

Comment: Where is the part wher you catch the submit and do something with the selected items?

Comment: Don't have that yet. Right now, the submit button does nothing. And the table just had a: Select *. and it echo's that.

Comment: Well you know what to do then.. Start coding..

Comment: But i don't understand how... :(

Comment: You press button, catch the button in post, catchth selected items from the select, do something with it so your query doesn't select all options, done..